# Change ABAP report language at runtime

Tags: report, translation, abap

I was under the assumption that each time I use the following statement during the runtime of an ABAP report, the text-symbols from the respective language would be used from there on out (if they were translated accordingly):

```
SET LANGUAGE 'EN'.
```

However, this language switch only seems to work once, because in my report (where I want the user to be able to select the output language) I can use any language I want during the first run. But once I go back to the selection screen and enter a different language code, the second `SET LANGUAGE` does not have any effect.

Is there some sort of text-symbols caching involved? Is there a way to prevent that for a single report or trigger a refresh at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution: There is none, since there is none needed.

SAP is not caching the language-dependent text symbols. You can at any point in the execution change the runtime language via:

```
SET LANGUAGE 'EN'.
```

The reason I thought it did not work was, that I was using an HTML control inlined in the SAP GUI that did not properly refresh and therefore on the second HTML display still showed the old language texts.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, it worths to use ***CL_GUI_TIMER*** to refresh the screen after you switched language. You can check it with ***SAP_TIMER_DEMO*** program.

Comment: I am failing to see how a timer is connected to my problem. Can you please elaborate. The timer does not refresh the screen but simply executes logic after a given interval.

Comment: I mean, to execute the report reloading when the event ***FINISHED*** will occur. Example of report auto-refreshing: http://www.sapdev.co.uk/reporting/rep_autorefresh.htm